# Regex functionality in g++ 5.1

Tags: regex, g++, gcc5

Is all the regex functionality finally implemented in gcc5.1? The previous versions only had partial support.

Comment: According to this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x, not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the [status of Regex implementation in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Regex/Status):

[image]